# NSDictionary - (for id foo in dict) vs (for NSString *foo in [dict allKeys])

Tags: objective-c

Suppose there is an `NSDictionary *dict`.
What is the difference between the following?

```
for (id key in dict) {
  NSLog(@"value: %@", dict[key]);
}

for (id key in [dict allKeys]) {
  NSLog(@"value: %@", dict[key]);
}
```

I didn't know that the first version existed, and when I saw it I thought it would be a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first variant uses NSDictionaries implementation of "fast enumeration" (NSFastEnumeration Protocol), while the second uses the NSArray implementation. I suspect that the first variant would be ever so slightly faster (at least it is a little less typing).

BTW you can also write

```
for (NSString *key in dict)
{
     NSLog(@"value: %@", dict[key]);
}
```

Note that unlike what a previous poster suggests, this is NOT a guarantee that all keys are NSString objects. It merely is an implicit casting of `key` to `NSString *`.

Comment: I suspected that this was the case. Thanks for verification. Would you happen to know where in Apple's docs this information is?

Comment: It is mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id key in dict) {
  NSLog(@"value: %@", dict[key]);
}
```

here you are not sure wether your key is `NSString` or `NSNumber` or any `NSObject`

```
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
  NSLog(@"value: %@", dict[key]);
}
```

whereas in this code snippet you are sure that the keys for the dictionary is NSString

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the point to the question. I've updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference. Both versions do the same.